# MC 4.8.13 uses Ctrl-Backspace for directory hotlist

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc

I just built GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.13 from source and the directory hotlist is now invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>.

This is a PITA since it seems to not be passed through via `ssh` -- or else it plain does not work, this is a remote system so that's the only access I have.

Rather than sorting that out, I'd prefer to have the old Ctrl-\ back, but I could not find anything relevant in the `.configure` options and it seems to be hard-coded in.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to recompile, but this is not hard to fix.  First, `make clean`.

Edit `mc-4.8.13/src/keybind-defaults.c`.  Find line 104/105:

```
/* To access the directory hotlist */
{"HotList", "ctrl-backspace"},
```

Change that to:

```
/* To access the directory hotlist */
{"HotList", "ctrl-\\"},
```

Configure as before and `make && make install`; done.